# Workflow doesn't work because tests create and open a database

Tags: python, sqlite, github, github-actions

My GitHub workflow that runs tests on different versions of Python:

```yaml
name: Tests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - Development

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.8", "3.9", "3.10", "3.11"]
        
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
      
      - name: Run Tests
        run: python -m unittest discover -s ./tests -p '*.py'
```

One of the tests creates a connection to an SQLite database (`sqlite3.connect('MIND.db')`). This creates and opens the database. I get:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

I know about [permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs#overview) but don't know which one to set to `write` for it to work (as far as I know, the problem is that the workflow is not allowed to write, but I don't know how to fix this).

Comment: What is the database path in that test? Is it already there or do you create it on runtime? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Ah you might have already given the answer without you knowing. The database is created in a subfolder, but that folder is created only when the main application runs and that never runs when doing the tests. So it's trying to create a db in a folder that doesn't exist (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the database was attempted to be created in a folder that didn't exist. I added a command before the one that runs the tests that creates the missing folder. Now the workflow runs fine.